# angular $http.get error, unexpected token

Tags: angularjs, json, node.js, http, angular-http

I was just starting to test a simple API using this code:

```
$http.get('/api/products?limit=10').then(function (response) {
    console.log(response.status);
});
```

And I get this error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
>       at Object.parse (native)
>       at fromJson (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:1271:14)
>       at defaultHttpResponseTransform (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9460:16)
>       at http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9551:12
>       at forEach (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:340:20)
>       at transformData (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:9550:3)
>       at transformResponse (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:10319:21)
>       at processQueue (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14792:28)
>       at http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:14808:27
>       at Scope.$eval (http://localhost:8000/bower_components/angular/angular.js:16052:28)

Btw, with this non angular code, it works fine:

```
function httpGetAsync(theUrl, callback) {
    var xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function() { 
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 && xmlHttp.status == 200)
            callback(xmlHttp.responseText);
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET", theUrl, true); // true for asynchronous 
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}

httpGetAsync('/api/products?limit=10', function(response) {
    console.log(response);
});
```

Some code of the API:

```
res.writeHead(200, {
    'Content-Type': 'application/x-json-stream'
});

// random delay
setTimeout(function () {
    var i;
    for (i=0; i<limit; i+=1) {
        res.write(JSON.stringify(createRandomItem(i+skip, sort)) + '\n');
    }
    res.end();
}, 100 + Math.floor(Math.random() * 3000));
```

I really can't figure out what's the problem, also already tried $resource and didn't worked.
You can see the whole code [on my github](https://github.com/fredericojesus/ascii-warehouse), please help.

Comment: the error is saying that when the `response.data` is received and passed through `fromJson()`, the `response.data` has an invalid `{` present that makes the `data` not a valid Json object.  Can you log the `response` and verify that you are passing valid Json?

Comment: I added res.write('{'); and res.write('}'); in the api before and after the for loop and it worked, but why was it working with xmlHttpRequest and not with angular $http ? so strange ...

Comment: the non angular may work because you aren't parsing the response so it doesn't care if valid json is returned. `$http` handles the parsing and it's the parsing thaat is throwing error. Take what was returned in non angular console and paste it into a json validator...most likely it fails

Answer (score 0):

I solved it in the client like this:

```
var WareHouseResource = $resource('/api/products?limit=10', {}, {
        query: {
            method: 'GET',
            isArray: true,
            transformResponse: function(data) {
                data = ('[' + data + ']').replace(/}/g, '},').replace(',\n]', ']');
                return angular.fromJson(data);
            }
        }
    });
```